# How can I have my Substratum Theme change two parts of the same file as two different options?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm making a Substratum theme for Viper4Android 2.7.1.0 and I see that after decompiling the original V4A App, in res/values/colors.xml, there are two lines that are for the background color and the accent color. I want to be able to make my theme change those lines individually as Background and Accent, but Substratum, as far as I know, can only replace the file, so it would be a pain to make a file for every combination.

I'm thinking of making these lines get their colors from some other .xml files that I'll add externally so that I can change those external XMLs with ease

This is the res/values/colors.xml file. There are other lines but these are the ones I'm working with.

```
<resources>
<color name="colorAccent">#ff6200ee</color>
<color name="colorPrimary">#ffffffff</color>
</resources>
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
<resources>
<color name="colorAccent">@(res/values/SubsAccent.xml)</color>
<color name="colorPrimary">@(res/values/SubsBackground.xml)</color>
</resources>
```

Then have a res/values/SubsAccent.xml and res/values/SubsBackground.xml with their own information that can be easily replaced with Substratum. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change this everytime then you need to create a code in your java file.

Try removing the brackets and make sure the path is correct and you are supposed to add the color path to your xml not vice-versa.

Another thing make sure that you cannot make a duplicate name color in your colors.xml file.

```
<resources>
<color name="colorAccent">@res/values/SubsAccent.xml</color>
<color name="colorPrimary">@res/values/SubsBackground.xml</color>
</resources>
```

Not sure but maybe this can help in your error solving.

Comment: So in the SubsAccemt.xml, for example, do I put just this: #FFFFFFFF, or do I need to add some thing like <color>#FFFFFFFF</color>? Or do I need to have that between <resources></resources>?

Comment: yes,you need to add the <resources> ......... </resources> tag first in that add  the 
<color> u want first then only it will be able to read your color.E.g:-<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color> </resources>

Comment: I tried replacing the actual color in colors.xml with the link to a Subs_Back.xml like you showed and put my color in the Subs_Back between the <resources> like you showed. However, Substratum gives an error when compiling the theme, saying that the "colorPrimary" in the colors.xml has already been defined in the Subs_Back.xml. Anyways to counter this?

Comment: The above was the example I have given you you need to change the color name,you cannot have 2 same names file or object.